# How do I interactively reduce (or stop) jquery carousel transition speed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

In the link http://www.getushopping.com/ code for the top slider which shows 7 images at a time is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
            wrap: 'circular'
            /*,size:9*/
            ,visible:7
            ,auto:true      
        });
    });     
</script>
```

I am new to javascript and jquery and I am facing many troubles. I want to reduce the transition speed and I also want want to stop the carousel when the mouse cursor hovers over it.

Comment: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/#Configuration

Answer (score 0):

add animation: option to configuration:

```
$('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        wrap: 'circular'
        /*,size:9*/
        ,visible:7
        ,auto:true,
        animation: 2000 // in miliseconds      
    });
```